# format output to body of mail using powershell

Tags: email, powershell, formatting

I want to display the disk size of certain directory and file for a particular directory in a formatted output and send it as a body in the mail using powershell.

I used in the powershell code but not able to save the same in a variable:

```
     C:\Users\abc\Desktop\xyz\file.bat -Name powershell | Format-Wide
```

The file.bat is  :

```
    cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Resource Kit
    diruse  /M /* C:\Users\abc\Desktop
```

and the output is :

```
Size (mb)  Files  Directory
     0.18     23  SUB-TOTAL: C:\USERS\abc\DESKTOP\xyz
    76.40      5  SUB-TOTAL: C:\USERS\abc\DESKTOP\testreport
    76.58     28  TOTAL
```

I want to print this output in the body of the mail using powershell.
Could any one please look into it as how to save the formatted output in a variable in powershell so that i can get the output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get an approximate format of that in an email body by piping it through `Out-String`

```
$body = C:\Users\abc\Desktop\xyz\file.bat -Name powershell | Format-Wide | Out-String
```

Note that your column alignment will not be exactly as you see it in the console, because the email client will use proportional fonts, where the console uses a fixed width font.

Comment: but the output in mail is not coming in a formatted way..It is coming in a single line :  C:\Users\abc\Desktop\xyz>cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Resource Kit C:\Program Files (x86)\Resource Kit>diruse /M /* C:\Users\abc\Desktop Size (mb) Files Directory 0.18 24 SUB-TOTAL: C:\USERS\abc\DESKTOP\xyz76.40 5 SUB-TOTAL: C:\USERS\abc\DESKTOP\testreport 76.58 29 TOTAL                                                     but I need the output in the mail as a formatted one

Comment: Piping formatted output through Out-String has always worked for me for adding the output to an email body.  Can't explain why it's not working for you, and don't really have time to reproduce that environment to debug it.